# Is there a way to track what the user has selected and show it on a separate page using jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I created some CSS that I want to show in a separate page using jQuery.

I got a reveal link that will show the color after it's pressed which will show the separate page with the color added to it also.

Each CSS style changes in size depending on what CSS image is clicked is pressed.

If the `happymyleast` gets selected it will show the small CSS part in a separate page.

If the `happycharactertwo` gets selected it will show a size that is bigger than the small CSS part so each time it changes in size.

I hope this makes sense to someone as I know what I want to do.

This is the code for it

```
#happymyleast{
    position: absolute;
    top: 119px;
    left: 71px;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    background-color: #FFCC00;
    border-radius: 44px;    
    border: 7px solid #ffe783;
}

#happycharactertwo{
    position: absolute;
    top: 170px;
    left: 66px;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    background-color: #FFCC00;
    border-radius: 44px;    
    border: 7px solid #ffe783;
}
```

Comment: i am afraid its not really clear what you want, maybe you can show what you got so far via https://jsfiddle.net/ ? 
Generally speaking there is nothing that would make a particular user action persistent unless you do it, you might want to look in to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage .

Comment: I'm working on the jsfiddle I will post it here when It's done.

Comment: I've done a jsfiddle but left out the jquery as sometimes it don't work. here is the link to the jsfiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/lr16/e481uh5e/3/